# Excute action sequencely in redux

Tags: redux

I have 2 actions onBoardingUserStart and authenUserSuccess, I want do authenUserSuccess after finishing onBoardingUserStart. But maybe it do at same time.

```
  successMeta = tokenObj.nickname ? onSuccess : onSuccess;
                successActions.push(
                  //
                  actions.onBoardingUserStart(),
                  actions.authenUserSuccess({
                    ...res,
                    ...tokenObj,
                  }),

                  actions.getMyDetailInfoRequest()
                );
```